# How to migrate settings for all Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use Chrome on a Windows 10 laptop. I recently got a new laptop and began migrating all of my apps, data etc. to the new laptop. When I installed Chrome on the new laptop and signed in, Chrome synced all of my extensions, bookmarks, etc. However, many of my extensions have particular options/settings which were not synced (e.g. default bookmark folders or default backup locations, etc.) Also, many of these extensions did not have the option to export/import settings. So, I had to look back at my previous installation (thankfully it's still available) and manually re-enter the settings on my new laptop.

This manual migration of extension settings is problematic for a couple of reasons. It's tedious and time-consuming, but more importantly, if my previous Chrome installation wasn't available as a reference, I would have permanently lost many of these settings and I would not be able to remember/reproduce them on my new installation.

Is there a way to programmatically (or otherwise automatically within Chrome) to sync extension settings?

Comment: In short, copy those directories inside the browser profile that have the extension ids in their names. You can find tutorials/answers that show how to do it in detail.